# Inflate PNG compression manual

Tags: compression, png

I want to implement PNG data decoder from scratch. However i cannot find detailed step by step IDAT chunk compression/decompression manual. I read ZLIB docs and Data Compression The Complete Reference book. Do you have some reference to as detailed compression method as possible?
[image: Data of my PNG file]

Comment: Please don't put screenshots in questions. Especially unreadable ones.

Answer (score 1):

The deflate compression format is fully documented in [RFC 1951](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1951). The zlib wrapper around it is fully documented in [RFC 1950](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1950). You can also look at [puff.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/contrib/puff/puff.c) for an implementation of a deflate decoder, with the express purpose of elucidating the format.